# html tag for grouping forms?

Tags: html, forms

I thought I remember seeing this somewhere but maybe not.

Isn't there an HTML tag for grouping forms similar to the  tag for grouping headers?

so for example:

```
<fgroup>
    <form>
        <!-- misc. data -->
    </form>
    <form>
        <!-- misc. data -->
    </form>
</fgroup>
```

Comment: There is no official form-grouping tag in the specifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you're thinking of the fieldset tag?
There's nothing to group entire forms.

Comment: Just to expand on Su's answer, you can nest `fieldset` elements, which would allow you to break a single form into multiple "subforms", however they would all be submitted together to the same URL. Fieldsets are commonly used to create multistep forms where each step is a fieldset.